# Ruby/Sinatra/erb: 404 for loading image

Tags: ruby, image, sinatra, erb

i try to display a image but the response code is 404 in the log:

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [02/Nov/2013 11:23:55] "GET /public/images/gtk_refresh.png HTTP/1.1" 404 466 0.0030
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [02/Nov/2013:11:23:55 MEZ] "GET /public/images/gtk_refresh.png HTTP/1.1" 404 466
http://localhost:4567/main-> /public/images/gtk_refresh.png
```

rb file:

```
get '/main' do
  erb: main         
end
```

erb file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1

/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>hello world</title>
</head>

<body>    
    <img src="public/images/gtk_refresh.png" />     
</body>
</html>
```

i tried relative and absolute path to the image, bit it didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change:

```
<img src="public/images/gtk_refresh.png" />
```

to:

```
<img src="/images/gtk_refresh.png" />
```

Comment: I had a similar issue but even referring to the image src as `/images/image.png` results in a 404 for me. Is there any other setup that I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use url helper.

```
<img src="<%= url('/images/gtk_refresh.png') %>" />
```